# Unable to restore database in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, import

I created a database backup using the `expdp` command in Oracle 10g.  The backup appears to be created successfully.  However, while restoring using `impdp` command I get the following error message.

```
ORA-39083: Object type JOB failed to create with error: ORA-00001:
unique constraint (SYS.I_JOB_JOB) violated Failing sql is:  BEGIN
DBMS_JOB.ISUBMIT( JOB=> 4002, NEXT_DATE=> TO_DATE('2012-07-13
14:29:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'), INTERVAL=> 'sysdate + 10/1440',
WHAT=>
 'wwv_flow_mail.push_queue(wwv_flow_platform.get_preference(''SMTP_HOST_ADDRESS''),wwv_flow_platform.get_preference(''SMTP_HOST_PORT''));',
 NO_PARSE=> TRUE); END;

 Processing object type
 DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/POST_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA Job
 "TMSMV"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 1255 error(s) at 12:24:24
```

I used following commands:

```
expdp tmsmv/password full=y dumpfile=tmsdump20120113-558.dmp logfile=tmslog20120713-558.log

impdp tmsmv/password full=y dumpfile=tmsdump20120113-558.dmp logfile=tmslog20120713-558.log
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is already a job on the imported database with that job number.  Just recreate the job on the import database.

The job looks to be a queue so you could, depending on your business procedures, probably run the new job to test that everything is working.